# Need to extract the subnet id from the data source based on the region

Tags: terraform, output, datasource, subnet, vpc

I have data source module where I am extracting the subnet id by passing subnet name.

File is in the data module:

Module/data/data.tf

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc-id" {
  provider = "${var.region}"
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt-vpc"]
  }

}

data "aws_subnet" "subnetid" {
  provider = "${var.region}"
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.vpc-id.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt-private-subnet-0"]
  }
}
```

Variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  description = "vpc name"
  type        = string
  default     = "aws.west"
}
```

main.tf where Iam calling the data module.

```
module "data" {
    source  =   "./data"
    region = "aws.west"
}


output "subnet_id" {
    value = module.data.subnetid
}
```

Provider.tf

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source = "hashicorp/aws"
            #version = "~> 3.0"
            #configuration_aliases = [ aws.alternate ]
        }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1" 

}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  region = "us-east-2"

}
```

While running the terraform apply i am getting the below errors

Error: Invalid provider configuration reference
│
│   on data\data.tf line 2, in data "aws_vpc" "vpc-id":
│    2:   provider = "${var.region}"
│
│ The provider argument requires a provider type name, optionally followed by a period and then a
│ configuration alias.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid provider configuration reference
│
│   on data\data.tf line 11, in data "aws_subnet" "subnetid":
│   11:   provider = "${var.region}"
│
│ The provider argument requires a provider type name, optionally followed by a period and then a
│ configuration alias.
╵

Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 18, in output "subnet_id":
│   18:         value = module.data.subnetid
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.data is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "subnetid".

Comment: Could you please help us to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a region name to the module, and then trying to use a specific provider based on that, you need to actually pass the provider itself into the module (documented [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly)):

```
module "data" {
    source  =   "./data"
    providers = {
      aws = aws.west
    }
}
```

Then just completely remove the `provider = "${var.region}"` lines inside the data module code.

Comment: Hi Mark, how to get the id of the subnet from the data module . iam getting the below error.

Comment: Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 20, in output "subnet_id":
│   20:         value = module.data.subnetid
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.data is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "subnetid"

Comment: You have to define an `output` value inside the module. Did you do that?https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs

Comment: In the module i have created output.tf file as

Comment: output "subnet-id" {
  description = "The current bid status of the Spot Instance Request"
  value       = data.aws_subnet.subnetid
}

Comment: In the main module i am calling the data module and need the subnet id from the data module.

Comment: module "data" {
    source  =   "./data"
    providers = {
      aws = aws
    }
}

output "subnet-id" {
  description = "The current bid status of the Spot Instance Request"
  value       = module.data.aws_subnet.subnetid
}

Comment: Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 20, in output "subnet-id":
│   20:   value       = module.data.aws_subnet.subnetid
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.data is a object

Comment: I am getting the above error

Comment: Please quit spamming me with comments. If you have more code to share, edit your question to include all that code.

Comment: If you have an output named `subnet-id` in the module, then you would reference it via `module.data.subnet-id` It looks like you left out the `-` and then you tried some other invalid things.